# How can I prevent a method called by a Vue component from running every time the v-model changes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have a form that populates a number dropdown lists from an API, so I created a method that gets the list (`getList()`) from that API. The dropdowns are built using the Vuetify v-autocomplete component, which populate the list using the `items` prop and I am calling `getList()` from this prop.

My problem is that all of the questions share a v-model object to store the responses and every time the v-model changes, all of the autocompletes call the `getList()` method again to repopulate the lists. Since I have multiple questions and each is making an API call multiple times, this form is running quite slowly.

Here's an example of this:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-text-field label="text question" v-model="responses.text"></v-text-field>
      <v-autocomplete
        label="random question"
        :items="getList()"
        v-model="responses.autocomplete"
      ></v-autocomplete>

      <p>Text v-model: {{ responses.text }}</p>
      <p>Autocomplete v-model: {{responses.autocomplete}}</p>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        responses: {},
      }
    },

    methods: {
      getList() {
        console.log('Getting list')
        return ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Note that every time you add a new character to the text field, the `getList()` method is called (check the console).

My question is, is there a way to prevent the `getList()` method from getting called every time the v-model changes?

What I've tried:

- Giving each question its own v-model so they don't affect each other. Unfortunately this doesn't work. It looks like any time any of the data changes, the `getList()` method is called. See this other example:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-text-field label="text question" v-model="text"></v-text-field>
      <v-autocomplete
        label="random question"
        :items="getList()"
        v-model="autocomplete"
      ></v-autocomplete>

      <p>Text v-model: {{ text }}</p>
      <p>Autocomplete v-model: {{autocomplete}}</p>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        responses: {},
        text: '',
        autocomplete: '',
      }
    },

    methods: {
      getList() {
        console.log('Getting list')
        return ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

- Getting the lists in the `mounted` hook. While this solves this problem, I cannot use it in my case because the dropdown list of some questions are dependent on other questions. For example, if Question 1 gets a response of A, Question 2 will get list [x, y, z], but if the response is B, it will get list [q, r, s]. So I do need Question 2 to react to Qestion 1, but I don't need it to react to Question 3.

So yes, any tips on improving the performance of this component by calling `getList` only when it's actually needed?

Comment: The question should contain all code that is necessary to understand it. Otherwise it will become unintelligible if external link becomes unavailable. In your case you can use a computed instead of a method, that's what they are for

Comment: Thanks for the question feedback and the the tip on using computed option. That works on the example I provided. I will test it my project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already did, store the current list items in data, but instead of setting it in mounted, updated it through a watcher.

```
    watch: {
      'responses.text': {
        handler(current, old) {
          if (!this.needsReload(current, old)){
            return
          }
          this.listItems = this.getList(current)
        },
        immediate: true,
      },
    },
```

Setting the `immediate:true` flag will trigger an initial load when the watcher is set up.

In your example, you could use a computed, since `getList()` is synchronous, but when you call an API, you should stick to a watcher [since computeds should be free of side-effects](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#best-practices).

Here is the [updated playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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), where the list is filled according to the first letter in the text input.

Comment: That's great! If the answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted answer and/or vote on it. It's a bit silly, but it is how the site works